# Convert DataTable to json Dictionary with TableName as key

Tags: c#, datatable, json.net

Want to convert a datatable to the Dictionary object with key as table name and value as the rows in the datatable.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.TableName = "TableName";

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ClientId"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ClientName"));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ClientId"] = 1;
        dr["ClientName"] = "Pradeep";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["ClientId"] = 2;
        dr["ClientName"] = "Test";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Now convert this dt object to `Dictionary<string, object>`, which key is the table name and object name is the json string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your solution

```
String ClientJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
Dictionary<string,string> _clientDictionary= new Dictionary<string,string>();
_clientDictionary.Add(dt.TableName,ClientJson);
```